# Chrome not respecting video source inline media queries

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video, media-queries

Using the below, Chrome is not respecting the media queries to display the correct video source based on the device width. Chrome is just playing the first source it finds as you can see here: http://homeglobal.ch/. How can I fix this?

```
    <video id="intro-video" poster="img/poster.png" controls>
        <source src="videos/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-device-width:1600px)">
        <source src="videos/intro.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (min-device-width:1600px)">
        <source src="videos/intro-1600.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-device-width:1100px)">
        <source src="videos/intro-1600.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (min-device-width:1100px)">
        <source src="videos/intro-1100.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-device-width:481px)">
        <source src="videos/intro-1100.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (min-device-width:481px)">
        <source src="videos/intro-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="videos/intro-480.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
```

Comment: For some annoying reason: "Media query of the resource's intended media; this should be used only in a <picture> element." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source

Answer (score 30):

Unfortunally, Chrome is not supporting media queries for video html 5 tag. A work around for this is to use plain Javascript or Jquery. It is no pretty, but works even in chrome.

```
var video = $('#myvideo');

var WindowWidth = $(window).width();

if (WindowWidth < 1200) {
    //It is a small screen
    video.append("<source src='/img/homepage/640/splash.m4v' type='video/mp4' >");
} else {
    //It is a big screen or desktop
    video.append("<source src='/img/homepage/1080/uimain-1080.mp4' type='video/mp4' >");
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this is still necessary or if Chrome started to acknowledge this?

Comment: It doesn't as of June 2019 >.< – still looking for a proper polyfill...

Comment: Man! Such a shame that this works for picture tag but not video. Works for both in Firefox. I hope they add support soon. It would be good to see an option added for the poster image as well.

Comment: 2021.09. Still no support.

Comment: There will never be support - it was withdrawn in Chrome 34 source: https://walterebert.com/playground/video/media-queries/

Comment: 2023 March - Still no support.

Comment: Still not supported

Comment: This did not work for me (Chrome on Mac, Edge on Windows), I had to add src attribute to video element

Answer (score 9):

My implementation on Vanilla JS.

In the `video` tag, as the `data-src` attribute, specify the path to the default video. Inside the `video` tag, in the `source` tags, we specify the value of the two attributes `data-src` and `data-mw`.

`data-src` - is the path to the video file.

`data-mw` - is the maximum screen width at which this video should be shown.

This solution works automatically when the screen width changes. This is done using the `resize()` function.

```html
<video id="intro-video" data-src="/path/default.mp4" poster="img/poster.png" controls>
    <source data-src="/path/1600.mp4" data-mw="1600">
    <source data-src="/path/900.mp4" data-mw="900">
    <source data-src="/path/480.mp4" data-mw="480">
</video>
```

```js
class VideoResponser {
    constructor(selector) {
        const $video = document.querySelector(selector);
        this.options = { 
            selector, 
            breakpoints: { default: { src: $video.getAttribute('data-src') } } 
        };

        // get a list of video switching points and links to the videos themselves 
        $video.querySelectorAll('[data-src]').forEach(element => this.options.breakpoints[element.getAttribute('data-mw')] = { src: element.getAttribute('data-src') });
        $video.innerHTML = ''; // we clean up so that there is nothing superfluous 
        
        // run the handler and track the change in screen width
        this.responseVideo(this.options);
        this.resizer();
    }

    /** Function runs on resize  */
    resizer() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.responseVideo(this.options));
    }

    /** 
     * Change src value of video link to fit screen width 
     * 
     * @param {Object} options object with options 
     */
    responseVideo(options) {
        const {selector, breakpoints} = options; // get options
        let $video = document.querySelector(selector);
        const widthNow = $video.getAttribute('data-width-now') || null;
        const maxBreakpoint = Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(breakpoints).filter(key => key <= document.body.clientWidth).map(Number));
        const nowBreakpoint = maxBreakpoint || 'default'; // choose either the maximum value, if not, then the default 

        if(widthNow && widthNow == nowBreakpoint) return; // check if the video needs to be changed 

        $video.setAttribute('data-width-now', nowBreakpoint);
        $video.src = breakpoints[nowBreakpoint].src;
    }
}

new VideoResponser("#intro-video");
```

Comment: Very nice script. I just had to change the line for the maxBreakpoint constant to get it working:
const maxBreakpoint = Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(breakpoints).filter(key => key <= document.body.clientWidth).map(Number));

Comment: Thanks @Patricks I needed to as this as well.

Comment: For me there was another error, maxBreakpoint was -Infitiy, thus I had to change line `const nowBreakpoint ...` 
to:
`let nowBreakpoint = 'default'; // choose either the maximum value, if not, then the default 
 if (maxBreakpoint && maxBreakpoint != -Infinity) {
   nowBreakpoint = maxBreakpoint;
 }`

Answer (score 4):

```
<video class="desktop-video" autoplay playsinline preload="auto" muted loop width="100%">
    <source src="${pdict.desktop_video}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="${pdict.desktop_video}" type="video/mov">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
<video class="mobile-video" autoplay playsinline preload="auto" muted loop width="100%">
    <source src="${pdict.mobile_video}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="${pdict.mobile_video}" type="video/mov">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

Can be done in CSS like

```
.desktop-video {
    display: grid;

    @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
        display: none;
    }
}

.mobile-video {
    display: none;

    @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
        display: grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will preload both videos even if one of them is hidden, this is bad for performances especially in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for show different videos depending on the screen size:

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" preload="auto">
    <source src="/video/1920x1080.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script>
(function(){
  var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
  if (414 >= w && 916 >= h)
    document.querySelector("video source").setAttribute('src', '/video/414x916.mp4');
  else if (1280 >= w && 720 >= h)
    document.querySelector("video source").setAttribute('src', '/video/1280x720.mp4');
})();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Supported since Chrome 120**

Since Chrome 120 (December 2023) media query is supported for video  elements.

https://chromestatus.com/feature/5144127067127808

Answer (score -4):

I used a solution with `object-fit: cover;`

```
.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
        .video-wrapper {
                padding-top: 50%;
        }
    }

.video-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ikinone/pen/VwZgpzz)

Comment: This will not solve an issue with different video formats for each breakpoint, it will only show "nicer" one video.