# HTML5 media query video for different viewports (breakpoint not working)

Tags: css, media-queries, html5-video, viewport, breakpoints

I am new to stackoverflow and I need some help in HTML5 and CSS3 as I am a newbie to responsive design / media queries. (I have used the forum search, but I couldn't find an answer on my question.)

I would like to display different videos for different viewports.
Could you guys help me to fix the following HTML code:

```css
video {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="vid-container">
    <video id="video" controls>
        <source src="vid/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width: 1024 px)">
        <source src="vid/video1.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (min-width: 1024 px)">
        <source src="vid/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width: 1023 px)">
        <source src="vid/video2.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width: 1023 px)">
    </video>
</div>
```

Thank you guys a lot in advance for helpfull tipps, tricks and answers.
Cheers!

Comment: The width queries are misspelled. Remove the space before each `px`

Comment: Thank you for the input. I've tried it with deleting the space,but - somehow - it's still not working. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Not right now. Can you change the snippet into a complete, working example? It currently only shows a black screen and it's very difficult to see whether a breakpoint is hit that way! Also, what browsers and/or platforms are you testing with?

Comment: Ok, I am sorry - I think you're right, Mr Lister! It looks like a browser-related issue: Everything works as intended in firefox (different video's for different viewports etc.), but in chrome, it does only show the first video (for any device) and is not corresponding with the viewport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create different quality settings for videos, it is often seen that the 'media' attribute is included in the source-tag (which may be nested in the video-tag; as above). **Attention**: This is not recommended by the W3C as well as not supported by some browsers, such as Google Chrome. Different video quality settings may get implemented by using JavaScript instead: [Chrome not respecting video source inline media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907930/chrome-not-respecting-video-source-inline-media-queries)